# Excel I have multiple rows starting with a "Name" sepcific to each row. How do I replace particular cells of the rows with names of that row?

Tags: excel

This is what I have - What i need is specified below

```
       Milk Honey   Meat    Cheese  Mushroom
George  NO  X       NO       NO       NO
Tim     X   X       NO       X        X
Tom     NO  NO      X        NO       NO
Nick    X   X       NO       X        X
Mat     X   NO      X        X        X
Pat     NO  NO      X        NO       NO
```

I need each row having X to be replaced with the name in that particular row like specified below

```
       Milk Honey   Meat    Cheese  Mushroom
George  NO  George  NO       NO       NO
Tim     Tim Tim     NO       Tim      Tim
Tom     NO  NO      Tom      NO       NO
Nick  Nick Nick     NO      Nick     Nick
Mat   Mat   NO      Mat      Mat      Mat
Pat     NO  NO      Pat      NO       NO
```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry Guys could not add pic and my text came in a bad format .. All i need is

Comment: This is what I have - What i need is specified below

    Milk Honey Meat Cheese Mushroom
George NO X     NO      NO       NO
Tim     X X     NO      X       X
Tom     NO NO     X      NO       NO
Nick    X X     NO      X       X



I need each row having X to be replaced with the name in that particular row like specified below

    Milk Honey Meat Cheese Mushroom
George NO George  NO      NO       NO
Tim     Tim Tim     NO  [enter image description here][1]    Tim   Tim
Tom     NO NO     Tom      NO       NO
Nick  Nick Nick     NO     Nick     Nick

Comment: If this is in place then it will require vba.  What have you tried and where do you fail.

Comment: In place, write a VBA macro; if you can make a new table, just use the `INDEX` function, and incrementing row and column arguments, to return each entry; test to see if it s an "X" and, if it is, change the column argument to a `1`.  Post back with what you have tried if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers friends. I tried macro given by fox it worked instantly did not get to try others thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will do what you're looking for if you select the table, then run it. If you will be running the macro on the same cells every time, you can replace `For each cell in Selection` with `For each cell in ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F7")` or whatever your range is.

```
Sub Replacer()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Formula = "X" Then cell.Formula = cell.End(xlToLeft).Formula
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code,

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(i, j) = "X" Then
        Cells(i, j) = Cells(i, 1)
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]